# Why do Pentagon tilings not solve the Einstein Problem?

Tags: geometry, discrete-geometry, tiling

The [einstein problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_problem) *asks about the existence of a single prototile that by itself forms an aperiodic set of prototiles, that is, a shape that can tessellate space, but only in a nonperiodic way*. (This [Numberphile video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6aFcgATW9Mw) has more context).

Now there are [pentagonal shapes that tile the plane in a non-periodic way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_tiling#Nonperiodic_monohedral_pentagons_tilings).

> Why are these shapes no solution to the einstein problem?

I suspect that I misunderstand some criteria of [Aperiodic set of prototiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aperiodic_set_of_prototiles), but i cannot figure out what it is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They key is that such a tile can **only** tile the plane aperiodically.  The other tiles you cite do not satisfy this criterion because while they *can* tile the plane in an aperiodic fashion, there exist other tilings of that shape that are periodic.

Answer (score 5):

To add to heropup's answer, notice that even a square can tile the plane non-periodically (assuming by non-periodic we need a full rank sublattice of translational symmetries); just shift a subsequence of the columns in the usual integer lattice displaced tiling by some non-integer amount.

Take on the other hand the set of *Robinson tiles*. The shapes are important here, the decoration with lines on their interior just helps to prove their aperiodicity:

[image]

These tiles can tile the plane but the **only** way they can is in a non-periodic fashion. It is impossible for these tiles to tile periodically. These two criteria are necessary to be satisfied in order to be called an 'aperiodic' set of prototiles.

The full tiling looks as follows, where only the decoration has been left intact for the majority of the image:

[image]

Comment: Is your square example considered a non-periodic tiling?  It still has a periodic translational symmetry along the columns, even if you've disrupted the "row" direction.

Comment: True, I guess it depends on your definition. Some people would say that a tiling is periodic if it has a full rank sublattice of $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a group of translational symmetries. Otherwise would say one just needs the existence of a non-trivial symmetry, in which case the square example no longer works. Maybe a better example would be a square tiling where the squares are then further subdivided into a pair of right triangles randomly. Almost surely, the resulting tiling will be *fully* non-periodic.